# Excel Dynamic Solution for Cumulated Product / Running Product of an Array without SCAN or OFFSET

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I want to calculate the cumulated / running product of an array.

However, the solutions provided under these two questions are not quite what I want:

1. [Cumulated Products (Multiplications) of Array in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73746074/cumulated-products-multiplications-of-array-in-excel)
2. [Excel Dynamic Array formula to create a running product of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400019/excel-dynamic-array-formula-to-create-a-running-product-of-a-column)

In both of the solutions provided under those questions, the solution uses either the `SCAN()` function which is currently not available to me, or it uses `OFFSET()` which only allows for a *range*-type input as array, not an array generated with a function such as `SEQUENCE()`.

More explicitly: The array I want to calculate a running product of is `=SEQUENCE(D11,1,1-D23,D24)` where D11 is an integer, D23 and D24 are decimals.

Does anyone have an in-formula solution for this or do I have to do the intermediary step to 'write' the sequence into a range first and then use the `OFFSET()` function?

**Edit 1**:

An example for the `SEQUENCE()` function above would be `{0.97, 0.96, 0.95,  ..., 0.75}`

**Edit 2**:

I would of course be happy with an `OFFSET()` solution if there is a way to use it without a *range*-type array as input.

**Edit 3**:

Here is a numerical example of what I am trying to achieve without the itermediary steps.

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: @DattelKlauber what excel version do you have so we know what functions to use? You are trying to use a cumulative but your input is not a range and, so you need to use functions that support arrays as input. Would you provide a sample data (input and output) so we can understand better the scenario? Thanks

Comment: I think you can take logs then progressively add them using mmult but I don't have a computer available to check it

Comment: @PeterT OP wants a running product, ie with the array: `{0.97, 0.96, 0.95,  ..., 0.75}`  It would return `{0.97,0.9312,0.88464,...,0.02908}` not a single sum.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to achieve what @ScottCraner pointed out. DavidLeal please see Edit 3 for a numerical example. Thanks for taking a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your initial formulation and requirements and assuming the input data set has **only positives values**. On `F2` you can put the following formula. Since you can use `SEQUENCE` I assume you can use `LET` too.

```
=LET(n, B2, seq,LOG10(SEQUENCE(n,1,1-B3,B4)), seqInc, INT(SEQUENCE(n,n,0)/n)+1, 
 LUnitTriMatrix, --(seqInc >= TRANSPOSE(seqInc)), mult,
 MMULT(LUnitTriMatrix, seq), POWER(10, mult))
```

as @Dattel Klauber pointed in the comments to generate the `LUnitTriMatrix` can be simplified as follow: `=N((SEQUENCE(n)>=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(n))))` so the formula can be simplified as follow.

```
=LET(n, B2, seq,LOG10(SEQUENCE(n,1,1-B3,B4)), 
 seqInc, SEQUENCE(n), LUnitTriMatrix, N(seqInc >= TRANSPOSE(seqInc)), 
 mult,MMULT(LUnitTriMatrix, seq), POWER(10, mult))
```

**Note**: For this case `N()` function and `--()` operation both can be used:

This *solution doesn't require to create a range with the sequence*, instead it just uses the array generated based on sequence input parameters.

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: Columns **Sequence** and **Manual** are just for testing purpose.

### Explanation

The solution uses the following two main ideas:

**IDEA 1**: The solution suggested in the answer provided by @Alister of the question you shared as a reference: [Excel Dynamic Array formula to create a running product of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400019/excel-dynamic-array-formula-to-create-a-running-product-of-a-column). The idea is to use the following logarithm property:

```
log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)
```

and because `log(a)` is the inverse operation of `exp(a)`, i.e.

```
a = exp(log(a)), where a > 0
```

therefore

```
a*b = exp(log(a*b)) = exp(log(a) + log(b))
```

so we convert a product cumulated problem into a sum cumulated problem of log items.

**IDEA2**: To build [Lower Unitary Triangular Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) (`LUnitTriMatrix` for future reference) so we can use a matrix multiplication via `MMULT`. For example:

```
|1 0 0|   |a|    |a         |
|1 1 0| x |b|  = |a + b     |
|1 1 1|   |c|    |a + b + c |
```

The `LUnitTriMatrix` can be obtained via the following two sequences:

```
 seqInc, INT(SEQUENCE(n,n,0)/n)+1
```

for `n` equal `5` for example the output is:

```
|1 1 1 1 1|
|2 2 2 2 2|
|3 3 3 3 3|
|4 4 4 4 4| 
|5 5 5 5 5|
```

**Note**: The same can be achieved as follow: `TRANSPOSE(MOD(SEQUENCE(n,n,0),n)+1)`, it is a matter of preference.

and the corresponding transpose matrix: `TRANSPOSE(seqInc)`:

The following condition generates the desired matrix:

```
LUnitTriMatrix, --(seqInc >= TRANSPOSE(seqInc))
```

For example:

```
|1 1 1 1 1 1|    |1 2 3 4 5|   |1 0 0 0 0|
|2 2 2 2 2 2|    |1 2 3 4 5|   |1 1 0 0 0| 
|3 3 3 3 3 3| >= |1 2 3 4 5| = |1 1 1 0 0|
|4 4 4 4 4 4|    |1 2 3 4 5|   |1 1 1 1 0|
|5 5 5 5 5 5|    |1 2 3 4 5|   |1 1 1 1 1|
```

The rest is just to do the multiplication:

```
mult, MMULT(LUnitTriMatrix, seq)
```

and the inverse operation (power of ten): `POWER(10, mult)` gets the final result.

**Note**: I use `LOG10(x)`/`POWER(10,x)` because it is easier for testing purpose, but any other combination of log/exp function can be used with the same base, such as: `LN(x)`/`EXP(x)` or `LOG(x,b)`/`POWER(b,x)`.

Comment: Wow, yes all of the functions in your formula are available to me. I'll have to test it out tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Great explanation. This could also hold an array like in the second linked question. `=LET(a,{10;8;3;4;5},n, COUNTA(a), seq,LOG10(a), seqInc, INT(SEQUENCE(n,n,0)/n)+1, LUnitTriMatrix, --(seqInc >= TRANSPOSE(seqInc)), mult, MMULT(LUnitTriMatrix, seq), POWER(10, mult))`

Comment: @P.b, is the formula you posted a generalization of the one in the answer? i.e. will it work regardless of the input being a row vector or col vector?

Comment: @DavidLeal, formula works, thanks! and great explanation. For `LUnitTriMatrix ` the `INT` function seems to be a complicated though. The same matrix can simply be generated with `N(SEQUENCE(n)>=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(n)))`

Comment: @DattelKlauber I was not aware of this option to generate an `nxn` matrix with a single row/column sequence. I will include in my answer. Thanks

Comment: @DattelKlauber my understanding from P.b comment is that you can use as input any array you create in the form: `{a;b;c..;z}` instead of generating the sequence. The array has to be of size: `nx1` (column array) otherwise the `MMULT` would not work. I don't see any other difference from my formulation. Thanks P.b for your comment!

Comment: @Dattel Klauber An iferror could be used to repeat the formula with transposed array, but I don't see the point of that using a manual array. The point was that the formula would work without any range involvement. (So yeah David, you understood it correctly)

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the OP's question starting formula from the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400019/excel-dynamic-array-formula-to-create-a-running-product-of-a-column) and using LN and EXP.  We can use MMULT to get where we want:

```
=LET( a, LN(A1#),
       v, SEQUENCE( ROWS(a) ), 
       h, TRANSPOSE( v ),
       stagr, (v - h + 1) * (v >= h),
       m, IFERROR(INDEX( a, IF(stagr>0,stagr,-1), ), 0),
        EXP(MMULT(m,SEQUENCE(ROWS(m),,1,0))))
```

[image]

You should be able to replace the `A1#` with your SEQUENCE formula:

```
=LET( a, LN(SEQUENCE(D11,1,1-D23,D24)),
       v, SEQUENCE( ROWS(a) ), 
       h, TRANSPOSE( v ),
       stagr, (v - h + 1) * (v >= h),
       m, IFERROR(INDEX( a, IF(stagr>0,stagr,-1), ), 0),
        EXP(MMULT(m,SEQUENCE(ROWS(m),,1,0))))
```

Comment: Log solution is really clever, didn't think of that at all. Those functions are definitely available to me but I'll have to test it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: The formula works, thanks! The one presented by DavidLeal is a bit easier to understand though so I'll accept that one. Thanks again for your effort