# Unable to use BYCOL and SCAN in the same formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate running (cumulative) totals per column on a range (please see picture below).

If I use one SCAN function per column, it works. But I have to write as many SCAN functions as I have columns.

The problem is that I want to use a single dynamic array formula that includes all the columns, whether current or future.

When I try to use BYCOL together with LAMBDA and SCAN, it does not work. I wonder whether BYCOL is able to work with functions that SPILL.

If BYCOL is incompatible with SCAN, is there a workaround to use a single formula for all my running totals?

[image]

Comment: @vaoler this is a well known problem. Please check the answer I provided to this [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). Please check it and let me know if you can accommodate to your problem. If not then I can provide an answer. You need only `HSTACK` pattern for this I would say.

Comment: David, your formula is beyond my understanding, perhaps you can give me a hint

Comment: I understand @vsoler, please check my answer. I provided the specific explanation for your case, I hope it helps you to understand this pattern that you can use in many other similar situations.

Answer (score 5):

On cell `D2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(set, A2:B5, m, COLUMNS(set), seq, SEQUENCE(m,1),
 CUMULATE, LAMBDA(x, SCAN(0, x, LAMBDA(acc,item, acc+item))),
 DROP(REDUCE(0,seq, LAMBDA(acc,idx, HSTACK(acc, CUMULATE(INDEX(set,,idx))))),,1)
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

It also works without removing the first column via `DROP` if the accumulator is initialized properly, with the cumulative sum of the first column, as follow:

```
=LET(set, A2:B5, m, COLUMNS(set), seq, SEQUENCE(m,1),
 CUMULATE, LAMBDA(x, SCAN(0, x, LAMBDA(acc,item, acc+item))),
 REDUCE(0,seq, LAMBDA(acc,idx, IF(idx = 1, CUMULATE(INDEX(set,,idx)),
  HSTACK(acc, CUMULATE(INDEX(set,,idx))))))
)
```

### Update

An alternative is also the following solution using `MAP` with the same shape as the input range, so there is no need to add columns via `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern:

```
=LET(n, ROWS(A2:B5), m, COLUMNS(A2:B5), 
  rows, MAKEARRAY(n, m, LAMBDA(r, c, r)),cols, MAKEARRAY(n, m, LAMBDA(r, c, c)),
  MAP(rows, cols, LAMBDA(r, c, SUM(INDEX(A2:B5, 1, c):INDEX(A2:B5, r, c)) ))
)
```

**Note**: You cannot pass a name from `LET` to represent the range `A2:B5` inside a `LAMBDA` function for using a function/operation that expects a range such as building a range as follow: `INDEX() : INDEX()`. Check the answer from @JosWoolley to this question: [Using name variable from LET produces #VALUE! inside MAP using SUM with the range defined as INDEX : INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595902/using-name-variable-from-let-produces-value-inside-map-using-sum-with-the-rang)

### Explanation

`BYCOL` returns one cell per column, that is why you get `#CALC!` error related to [Nested Array Error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-calc-error-nested-array-ffa5997d-a440-4e41-aae9-8b39c4a8dfb9). It can be circumvent using `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern, explained here for example: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) answer provided by @DavidLeal.

For your particular case, we need to calculate the cumulative sum for each column. We created a user `LAMBDA` function for that: `CUMULATE`:

```
LAMBDA(x, SCAN(0, x, LAMBDA(acc, item, acc+item)))
```

Now we use the pattern to iterate over all columns. `REDUCE` function needs an input array, so we create a `seq` name with the column positions. We can access to each column of the input range (`set`), via `INDEX(set,,idx)`, where `idx` represents the column number.

Now we use the pattern `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` explained in the above link to generate each column:

```
DROP(REDUCE(0, arr, LAMBDA(acc, x, HSTACK(acc, func(x)))),,1)
```

In our case `func(x)` will be the user `LAMBDA` function we just created: `CUMULATE`, so in our case it will be:

```
DROP(REDUCE(0,seq, LAMBDA(acc,idx, HSTACK(acc, CUMULATE(INDEX(set,,idx))))),,1)
```

What it does is to invoke for each column of `set` the `CUMULATE` `LAMBDA` function and via `HSTACK` appends the column created on each iteration. The variable `acc` represents the accumulator, so we start with initial value of the accumulator `0`, then we add recursively via `HSTACK` the following columns. Finally we need to remove the first column via `DROP(result,,1)` that represents the first iteration that doesn't calculate the cumulative sum and just generate a column like this one:

```
0
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
```

**Note**: If an array has fewer rows than the maximum width of the selected arrays, `HSTACK` returns a `#N/A` error in the additional rows. That is why you get such values. Bottom line, the first column needs to be removed, because we didn't initialized with a valid value the first iteration. I provided a second alternative that doesn't require to remove this column but at the end is a more verbose formula. It is a matter of personal preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just employ some basic matrix multiplication?

`=LET(ζ,A2:B5,ξ,ROWS(A2:B5),MMULT(N(SEQUENCE(ξ)>=SEQUENCE(,ξ)),ζ))`

Comment: Good idea, I forgot about this approach, actually I used it here: [Excel Dynamic Solution for Cumulated Product / Running Product of an Array without SCAN or OFFSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74183936/excel-dynamic-solution-for-cumulated-product-running-product-of-an-array-witho/74186022#74186022). The question drives me to what I did in a similar situation to avoid this error, but this is also a great way.

Answer (score 3):

For alternatives sakes, based of on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74007255/9758194) answer (and comments):

[image]

```
=SCAN(0,B4:C7,LAMBDA(a,b,IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(b,-ROW(b)+1,0,ROW(b))),b)))
```

Or a non-volatile version:

```
=SCAN(0,B4:C7,LAMBDA(a,b,SUM(TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(B4:C7,COLUMN(b)-1),ROW(b)-3))))
```

Or, to make the latter more dynamic:

```
=LET(a,B4:C7,b,@COLUMN(a)-1,c,@ROW(a)-1,SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(d,e,SUM(TAKE(CHOOSECOLS(a,COLUMN(e)-b),ROW(e)-c)))))
```