# Get the average rank in excel

Tags: excel, ranking

I have a list of columns based on date

```
property | 2023-04-10 | 2023-04-11 | 2023-04-12
A        |    0:10    |    0:20    |   0:30
B        |    0:05    |    0:12    |   0:35
C        |    0:02    |    0:10    |   0:40
```

I want to compute a column which has average rank, that is

```
property | average_rank
A        |     (1+1+3)/3
B        |     (2+2+2)/3
C        |     (3+3+1)/3
```

how do I achieve this in excel, also some of the cells have blank entries, in that case I would not like consider that cell while calculating the average rank

there are 100s of columns so I cannot enter them one by one in the average function

Comment: isn't something like `=AVG(selectYourCols)` not working? You can mix it in with an `IF` statement to check for empty to skip it.

Comment: how do I combine with rank, I use, `=AVERAGE(RANK(ND17,ND$8:ND$500),  RANK(NE17,NE$8:NE$500))` but I cannot do this for 100s of columns

Comment: I'm not at all an expert in excel, but I understand sheet formula's and just trying to help and found [`RANK.AVG`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rank-avg-function-bd406a6f-eb38-4d73-aa8e-6d1c3c72e83a) function, would that be sufficient? As for 100 cells, you know you can copy with the bottom right corner drag right?

Comment: @Xorifelse `RANK.AVG` is intended for something different. Rank calculation has several variants, this is one of them, another one is `RANK.EQ`. In case more than one value has the same rank, returns the average. Per my understanding, the OP wants to find the rank for each element of the input matrix, then calculate per property (row) the average.

Comment: @DavidLeal Yeah I noticed i got the question or rather, the correlation wrong after the first answer so... my bad was just trying to be helpful polling extra info. Anyways impressive answers!

Answer (score 2):

Combination of latest functions of ***Microsoft-365*** may work.

```
=BYROW(
MAP(B2:D4,LAMBDA(x,RANK(x,INDEX(B2:D4,,COLUMN(x)-COLUMN(A2))))),
LAMBDA(rw,AVERAGE(rw))
)
```

We can avoid using of `RANK()` function using the following formula.

```
=BYROW(
MAP(B2:D4,LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(x,SORT(CHOOSECOLS(B2:D4,COLUMN(x)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:D4))+1),,-1)))),
LAMBDA(rw,AVERAGE(rw))
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should replace the reference to cell `A2` with something which references the range `B2:D4` for consistency.

Comment: How does the `XMATCH/SORT` combination compare to `RANK` when there are duplicates within a given column? Do they give the same results?

Comment: Then we may need to use `UNIQUE()` function based on output expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, *assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tag listed in the question*:

```
=LET(in,B2:D4,BYROW(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(in),COLUMNS(in), LAMBDA(i,j,
 RANK(INDEX(in,i,j),INDEX(B2:D4,,j)))),LAMBDA(z, AVERAGE(z))))
```

### Note

Under Excel for Web, I tested you can use `INDEX(in,,j)` instead of `INDEX(B2:D4,,j)`. As @JosWoolley pointed out in the comment section, testing the formula using the name `ìn` produces a `#CALC!` (Nested array error) for *desktop* under O365. I tested also for this desktop version: Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214 Current Channel). *A possible bug or inconsistency in Microsoft update/release channel policy*. I posted this issue in the Microsoft Feedback community, here is the [link](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/1fd463bb-87f5-ed11-a81c-000d3a7a48db), in case you would like to vote for it.

Another workaround to avoid this error and keep using the name `in`, is to create a `LAMBDA(B2:D4)` function, i.e. "thunking the range" and name it `in`, then to refer it. It ensures the formula is easier to maintain (if you need to update the range, update it in one place only). For example:

```
=LET(in, LAMBDA(B2:D4), BYROW(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(in()),COLUMNS(in()), LAMBDA(i,j,
 RANK(INDEX(in(), i,j), INDEX(in(),,j)))),LAMBDA(z, AVERAGE(z))))
```

Notice how we call it: `in()`.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

`MAKEARRAY` iterates over all elements of the input (`in`) and calculate the `RANK` for a given element (`i`,`j`) with respect to column `j` of `in`. Then we invoke `BYROW` on the `MAKEARRAY` result to calculate on each row the average.

Comment: Wow. Guess you've recently had a new and very important update to your version of Excel. That returns a `#CALC!` error for my version, since `RANK` requires a *range* for its second parameter, though in this particular construction `INDEX(in,,j)` returns an *array* for me. Has this update been documented anywhere, do you know? Can't wait to get it myself - game-changer!

Comment: Or perhaps you've mistakenly also stored *in* within Name Manager?

Comment: @JosWoolley, no, I am just using the formula I put in the answer. i am using Excel for Web the free version.

Comment: Can you confirm that it **doesn't** work as desired in the desktop version? This is a huge difference between the two if so.

Comment: Since you start by saying "*assuming no Excel version constraint as per the tag listed in your question*", I think you should amend to say that this is for Excel for Web only.

Comment: This drawback means that, if we want to declare the original range via `LET`, we have to come up with more involved constructions, e.g. `=LET(ζ,B2:D4,ξ,ROWS(ζ),BYROW(MAKEARRAY(ξ,COLUMNS(ζ),LAMBDA(α,β,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ξ,,0),N(INDEX(ζ,,β)>=INDEX(ζ,α,β))))),LAMBDA(κ,AVERAGE(κ))))`

Comment: Under my desktop version, yes I got a `#CALC!` error (nested array), that is weird, since as per [RANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) documentation it accepts for **Ref** input argument an array. Interesting, maybe a possible bug, or as you mentioned the Excel Web free version has been recently updated. I tried with `CHOOSECOLS` instead and it gives an Excel error in the formula

Comment: yes, I will update it @JosWoolley I didn't know that is not working under O365 for desktop version being the same version. That is the first time I see this.

Comment: @JosWoolley it works using the range in the `INDEX` call, so I updated the formula. We have seen that before, but this time seems to be something different, I remember we created the name using an inner `LET` as a workaround in another question we debated this, but this doesn't work this time.

Comment: I use 2016 excel

Comment: @JosWoolley this was the question I was referring too: [Using name variable from LET produces #VALUE! inside MAP using SUM with the range defined as INDEX : INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595902/using-name-variable-from-let-produces-value-inside-map-using-sum-with-the-rang) that you responded. Thanks!

Comment: @apostofes next time, use the appropriate tag in your question, I don't consider myself too familiar with the older Excel versions. Maybe other people from the community can help you with a solution to your specific version. Probably a very verbose approach, since it requires to iterate over the entire matrix.

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks for the reminder! The only slight issue with the set-up I propose in that link is that you still have to explicitly reference the range for `MAKEARRAY`'s *rows* and *columns* parameter, or else declare the range twice using `LET` (once internal to the `LAMBDA`, once external), which is not ideal. Hence my preference for a set-up which does not involve `RANK`.

Comment: @DavidLeal Re `RANK` accepting arrays as well as ranges, we've also discussed this before - appears to be an error in the official documentation.

Comment: Wow! `LAMBDA(B2:D4)`. What's this trickery?!

Comment: @JosWoolley sometimes Excel users have a lot of imagination to overcome some of the Excel limitations, odd behaviors or lack of documentation, :-). I took the idea from: Sergei Baklan, from this post: [MAXIFS doesn't work inside MAP using names from LET](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/maxifs-doesn-t-work-inside-map-using-names-from-let/m-p/3681425#M171470) from Microsoft Technical Community. I don't really know the logic behind, it seems to return the range, not an array, so it works